# How to display date of birth in dd-mm-yyyy format in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

I am getting a date of birth in yyyy-mm-dd format. I want it in dd-mm-yyyy format. How can this be done in Ruby?

Here is my code:

**index.html:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 dob">
    <%#= f.input :date_of_birth %>
  <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth,
    {:start_year => Time.now.year,
     :end_year => 1900,
     :use_short_month => true,
     :order => [:month, :day, :year],
     :prompt => {:day => 'Day',:month => 'Month', :year => 'Year'}}
 </div>
```

**show.html:**

```
<div class="col-md-10 primary-info-label">
  <label><%= @user.date_of_birth %></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the format of the date of birth in your view, you can use `strftime`:

```
<div class="col-md-10 primary-info-label"> 
  <label><%= @user.date_of_birth.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></label>
</div>
```

The above should format the date_of_birth to be in mm-dd-yyyy format. More info on `strftime` [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you ,thanks a lot ..@Zoran ... solved.. first i got error , so that i included quoteslike this ,now solved      `
              <%= @user.date_of_birth.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>
              `

Comment: Ahh duh! Thanks for pointing that out - I'll update my answer to put in the quotes :)